# tm.plugin.sentiment not available for R version 3.3.2

Tags: r

In the RStudio console, after I "run":

```
install.packages(c('tm', 'tm.plugin.sentiment'))
library(tm)
library(tm.plugin.sentiment)

warning: package ‘tm.plugin.sentiment’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2).
```

I then tried to install using Packages-install, but the same warning came up.
The repository was CRAN, CRANextra. I was using a 32-bit windows platform. A friend using a Mac also got the same warning message. 
The friend who shared the code with us used the same R version 3.3.2 but did not have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(devtools) # try install.packages('devtools') if you don't have it installed
install_github("mannau/tm.plugin.sentiment")
library(tm.plugin.sentiment) # should work
```